# fill multiple animation cells in Clip Paint Studio

Tags: animation, clip-studio-paint

I have 8 frames of line art animation that I want to fill.
Fill meaning adding a silhouette to the line art.
I am currently filling by setting the line art as a reference layer and using magic wand to fill. However I have to do this for each frame. Is there a way to fill all 8 frames automatically without having to manually select and fill for each frame?
Thank you!

[image: line art]
[image: filled line art]

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using auto action is currently the best method.

Comment: What "auto action" are you referencing?